# How to make pipeline stage grid be displayed as Unstable when the pytest job has failed tests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pytest

I have 4 jenkins jobs, all are about pytest, the shell command for each job is like

```
pytest -v --junitxml=result.xml || exit 0
```

the reason why I add  `|| exit 0` is because I want each job run one by one, even any of the jobs fail

and I create a pipeline job, the pipeline script is as below

```
node {
    stage('win10_chrome90_admin') {
        build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_admin', propagate: false
    }
    stage('win10_chrome90_salesman') {
        build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_salesman', propagate: false
    }
    stage('win10_firefox88_admin') {
        build job: 'UI_automation_win10_firefox88_admin', propagate: false
    }
    stage('win10_firefox88_salesman') {
        build job: 'UI_automation_win10_firefox88_salesman', propagate: false
    }
}
```

so every time when I run the pipeline, the stage view is always green, I cannot tell if any job has failed tests, actually the 2nd job in the image is displayed as unstable after clicking into its job view.

Is there any way to make the grid of the job display as yellow(unstable) when it has failed tests?(the same as what I see after clicking into the job)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pytest plugin `pytest-custom-exit-code` in pytest, so the shell command in my test job is something like

`pytest -v --junitxml=result.xml --suppress-tests-failed-exit-code`

and in my pipeline job, the pipeline script is something like

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('win10_chrome90_admin') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_admin'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('win10_chrome90_salesman') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_salesman'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('win10_firefox88_admin') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_firefox88_admin'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally my pipeline(run 4 test jobs one by one) run like below, if any test job has failed tests, the stage grid will show Unstable(yellow color), and the next job will continue to be launched
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')` in this case, so that the pipeline is successful, but stage is showed as failed.
You  can choose the status of buildResult and stageResult in case you want it to be unstable or fail.
Example pipeline:
In the below example, even if stage "Testing" fails , other stages will still be executed and the stage "Testing" will be marked as failure in the view.

```
stage("Testing") {
          steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                script {
                         
                        // You can execute your commands without || exit 0
                   }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT** : You can also acheive the unstable behaviour by adding it in below way:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('win10_chrome90_admin') {
            steps {
               script{
                try {
                
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_admin'
                    }
                     catch (e){
                   unstable('win10_chrome90_admin failed!')
                   }
               }
            }
        }

        stage('win10_chrome90_salesman') {
            steps {
                script{
                try {
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_salesman'
                }
                catch (e){
                   unstable('win10_chrome90_salesmanfailed!')
                   }
               }
          }
        }
        stage('win10_firefox88_admin') {
            steps {
              script{
                try {
                
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_firefox88_admin'
                    }
                     catch (e){
                   unstable('UI_automation_win10_firefox88_adminfailed!')
                   }
               }  
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just try, but it doesn't work, the pipeline could run well, the jobs run one by one even it fails(not all tests pass), the pipeline code is like `pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('win10_chrome90_admin') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
                    build job: 'UI_automation_win10_chrome90_admin', propagate: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: please note that I change `node` to `pipeline` in my pipeline script

Comment: I find the solution, will post here soon

Comment: @Reed_Xia :  you can execute with  ``propagate: true`` and catcherror parts remain same. This gives the output

Comment: @Reed_Xia I have also added code for showing  unstable behaviour . A plugin is not needed and will give you the same output